# Patching SQL Server 2008 and upgrading to 2014

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, update, service-pack

The environment which I am working right now is on SQL Server 2008, 2008 R2. Do you think its a good idea to first patch it with the latest service pack and then upgrade to SQL Server 2014?

Thanks

Comment: It's never a good idea to do an in-place upgrade. What is your rollback strategy if something goes wrong? Much better to build a new machine with SQL Server 2014 already, then restore the database, or attach a copy of the data and log files.

Comment: While I agree with Randolph that doing a side-by-side upgrade is better (for so many reasons), some people just don't have resources to stand up a new server and are forced to go in-place.  It's a very good point about the rollback strategy, with in-place there's not much you can do if it goes sideways or you'll need a lot of help putting humpty-dumpty back together again.

Comment: Apologies if I did not put the question right. I never meant in place upgrades. I was refering to side by side upgrades. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, yes it's a good idea to patch to the latest service pack *and* cumulative update (Microsoft is known to release new features in CUs as well). Spörri's answer is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The [SQL Server 2014 Upgrade Techincal Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/5/715BDFA7-51B6-4D7B-AF17-61E78C7E538F/SQL_Server_2014_Upgrade_technical_guide.pdf) states that  you need the following as the minimal version for an in-place upgrade

- SQL Server 2005: SP4 is required.
- **SQL Server 2008: SP2 is required.**
- **SQL Server 2008 R2: SP1 is required.**
- SQL Server 2012: SP1 is required

So if you are not on the stated service pack level you will need to upgrade to at least that.

It is not neccessary, but start by running the upgrade advisor. 
Thomas LaRock has a [checklist](http://thomaslarock.com/2014/06/upgrading-to-sql-server-2014-a-dozen-things-to-check/) on his page both for the tasks needed before an inplace upgrade and what to do afterwards.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got a downvote on this.